# foreach multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, multidimensional-array

How do i loop through the following array with a foreach, so it gets printed like this:

```
Product1 date1 time1
product2 date2 time2
product3 date3 time3
product4 date4 time4
```

I have been struggling and strugling, i tried double foreaches etc, but somehow i don't get it to work...

Is Anyone able to explain it to me?

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => product1
            [1] => product2
            [2] => product3
            [3] => product4
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => date1
            [1] => date2
            [2] => date3
            [3] => date4
        )

    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => time1
            [1] => time2
            [2] => time3
            [3] => time4
        )

)
```

Comment: Using a for loop would be more applicable based off of your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$count = count($data['product']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
    echo $data['product'][$i] . ' ' . $data['date'][$i] . ' ' .$data['time'][$i] . '<br />';
}
```

To add data-verification/integrity to it (to stop `undefined index` errors), also check if each index exists in the sub-arrays:

```
$count = count($data['product']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $date = isset($data['date'][$i]) ? ' ' . $data['date'][$i] : '';
    $time = isset($data['time '][$i]) ? ' ' . $data['time '][$i] : '';
    echo $data['product'][$i] . $date . $time . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: With the updated answer and corrected array access after your first update, ok +1.

Comment: Thanx man! Exactly what i was looking for. I couldn't understand how to do it with just a for(), but now i do!

Answer (score 3):

simple

```
<?php
    foreach($array['product'] as $num => $prod){
        echo $prod." ".$array['date'][$num]." ".$array['time'][$num];
    }
?>
```